# Unable to receive Broadcast In Same Activity

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, intentfilter

So i was learning about BroadcastReceiver in android. BroadcastReceivers are based on observer design patterns (which makes them very interesting).
So what i am trying to achieve is to broadcast my message and inside same activity i want to receive the message (Just for testing purpose).
Here is the code snippet

```
    Log.d("ABC", "sending");
    Intent intent = new Intent("com.yourcompany.testIntent");
    intent.putExtra("value", "test");
    sendBroadcast(intent);



    Log.d("ABC", "sent");

    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter("com.yourcompany.testIntent");
    BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Log.d("ABC","INSIDE ");
            String value =  intent.getExtras().getString("value");
        }
    };

    Log.d("ABC", "receiving");
    registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
    Log.d("ABC", "received");
```

Here is the debugged output

> 04-06 20:40:52.446
>   20149-20149/com.example.illuminati.broadcastreceiver D/ABC: sending
>   04-06 20:40:52.447
>   20149-20149/com.example.illuminati.broadcastreceiver D/ABC: sent 04-06
>   20:40:52.448 20149-20149/com.example.illuminati.broadcastreceiver
>   D/ABC: receiving 04-06 20:40:52.453
>   20149-20149/com.example.illuminati.broadcastreceiver D/ABC:received

Why it is not getting inside onReceive() method
What am i missing here
Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are sending your broadcast message before registering broadcast receiver. Try doing in the following way and it will work:

```
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter("com.yourcompany.testIntent");
    BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Log.d("ABC", "INSIDE ");
            String value = intent.getExtras().getString("value");
        }
    };
    registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
    Intent intent = new Intent("com.yourcompany.testIntent");
    intent.putExtra("value", "test");
    sendBroadcast(intent);
```

Comment: Such a silly mistake . I can't  thank you enough . Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

Also you should consider using the LocalBroadcastManager if you want to broadcast a message inside your app (and not to every apps installed). See https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.html